# Does # in an excel formula move you to the last cell in the dataset?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a `#` in my formula and it showed up because I hit CTRL+DOWN when selecting to move to the last cell in the dataset.

Is that what it represents?

For example `$A$1#` would take you to the last record the way you would normally have to write `$A$1:$A$90` where `90` is the row at the bottom of the set.

Comment: `#` indicates to take the result of the spilled dynamic array formula and can only be used with them.  If you have hand entered data in those cells it will not automatically find the bottom.

Comment: @ScottCraner `Spilled dynamic array formula` you mean like a MAP / LAMBDA?

Comment: There are many many dynamic array formula that will spill a result.  It could be as simple as `=A1:A10` to a multi nested formula.  But if the cell to which you refence does not contain a formula that spilled results using the `#` will not return the used range.

Comment: Here is a good explanation: https://www.xelplus.com/excel-hash-sign-formulas/#:~:text=The%20purpose%20of%20the%20HASH,Excel%20%23SPILL!